# importing csv datetime error in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, csv

I have a csv file I'm trying to import where the datetime from Oracle was exported like this:

```
to_char(t1.D_DTM, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mm:ss')
```

I'm trying to import it into mysql like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/import/IPORT17/IPORT17.csv' INTO TABLE ds3r05
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(@D_DTM,    TECHNOLOGY, VOICEDATA,  MRKT_NM,......  )
SET mydate = STR_TO_DATE( @D_DTM, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%S');
```

but keep getting this error:

```
ERROR 2 (HY000): Wrong data or column definition. Row: 1, field: 1.
```

I've also tried this:

```
STR_TO_DATE( @D_DTM, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%S');
```

but get the same error...

i created the table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `DS3R05`
( `D_DTM` DATETIME, 
`TECHNOLOGY` VARCHAR(5) comment 'lookup', 
`VOICEDATA` VARCHAR(5) comment 'lookup', 
`MRKT_NM` VARCHAR(20) comment 'lookup', 
`REGION_NM` VARCHAR(20) comment 'lookup', 
`CLUSTER_NM` VARCHAR(60) comment 'lookup', 
`BSC_NM` VARCHAR(5) comment 'lookup', 
`BTS_ID` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, 
`CSCD_NM` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`SECT_SEQ_ID` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BND_ID` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`FA_ID` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`TCE_DTCT_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MS_ACQ_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SIGN_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BAD_FRM_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`REORG_ATT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`TCE_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`WCD_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`L_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`TRAF_FRM_MISS_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BCP_TMO_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`PWR_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SDU_EXCP_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SDU_RSPNS_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CMP_OVLD_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`A1P_OOS_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BS_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BS_CONT_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MSC_TMO_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SVC_NEGO_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SDU_IDL_FRM_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`TCE_IDL_FRM_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BCP_OVLD_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BCP_CEP_TMO_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BAD_FRM_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BAD_FRM_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BS_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`BS_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`TCE_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SDU_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MGW_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`TCE_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SDU_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MGW_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MBL_ACQ_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`TCC_MSG_TMO_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`TCE_RQST_ERR_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`ATP_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`RSRC_ALOC_ERR_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`DMC_MSG_TRANS_ERR_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`A8_CONN_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MBL_AUTHT_SCP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`NW_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`DMC_BRR_PATH_SET_TMO_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`L_LOST_CALL_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`HWR_ID_RSPNS_TMO_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`DSP_ALOC_TMO_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`DCC_CE_ALOC_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`ATT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`AXS_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CE_BLK_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CUST_BLK_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`DRP_CALL_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`HHI_ATT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`HHI_BAFRM_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`HHI_CALL_SETUP_SXS_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MBL_ORG_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MBL_TER_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`NON_BTS_EQ_BLK_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`PRIM_CALL_ERL` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`PWR_BLK_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SFUL_CALL_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SILENT_RETRY_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`T1_BHL_BLK_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`WCD_BLK_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SMS_ATT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SMS_SXS_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CTRL_CH_USG_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CTRL_SL_USG_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`DO_SECT_PHL_FWD_PS_TMS` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`DO_SECT_PHL_REV_PS_TMS` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`EUSR_CONN_SETUP_ATT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`EUSR_CONN_SETUP_F_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`FWD_D_TRANSD_QTY` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MAC_ID_BLK_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MAC_ID_UTIL_RT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MS_RQST_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MS_RQST_D_QTY` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`NORM_CONN_CLS_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`NORM_SESS_RLS_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`RAB_SET_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`RCVD_RAB_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`REV_AIR_PER_BAD_FRM_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`REV_AIR_PER_TRSF_D_QTY` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`REV_D_TRANSD_QTY` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`RNC_BLK_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SESS_ATT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SESS_CONF_SXS_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`SL_USG_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MAX_USER_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`AVG_USER_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`MOU_TMS` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC0` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC1` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC4` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC5` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC6` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC8` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC9` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC10` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC11` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC12` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC13` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC14` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC15` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC16` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC17` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC18` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC19` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC20` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC21` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC22` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC23` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC24` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC25` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC26` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC27` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC28` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC29` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC30` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC31` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC32` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC33` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC34` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC35` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC36` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC37` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC38` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC39` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC40` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC41` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC42` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC43` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC44` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC45` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC46` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC47` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC48` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC49` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC50` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC51` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC52` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC53` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC54` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC55` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC56` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC57` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC58` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC59` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC60` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC61` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC62` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC63` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC64` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC65` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC66` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC67` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC68` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC69` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC70` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC71` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC72` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC73` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC74` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC75` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC76` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC77` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC78` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC79` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC80` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC81` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC82` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC83` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC84` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC85` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC86` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC87` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC88` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC89` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC90` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC91` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC92` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC93` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC94` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC95` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC96` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC97` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC98` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC99` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC100` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC101` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC102` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC103` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC104` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC105` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC106` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC107` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC108` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC109` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC110` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC111` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC112` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC113` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC114` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC115` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC116` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC117` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC118` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC119` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC120` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC121` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC122` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC123` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC124` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC125` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC126` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC127` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC1000` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC1001` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC1002` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC1003` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2000` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2001` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2002` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2003` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2004` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2005` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2006` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2007` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2008` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2009` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2010` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2011` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2012` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2013` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2014` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2015` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2016` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2017` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2018` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2019` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2020` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2021` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2022` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2023` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2024` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2025` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2026` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2027` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2028` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2029` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2030` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2031` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2032` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2033` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2034` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2035` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2036` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2037` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2038` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2039` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2040` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2041` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2042` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2043` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2044` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2045` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2046` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2047` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2048` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2049` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2050` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2051` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2052` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2053` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2054` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2055` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2056` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2057` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2058` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2059` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2060` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2061` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2062` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2063` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2064` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2065` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2066` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2067` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2068` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2069` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2070` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2071` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2072` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2073` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2074` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2075` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2076` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2077` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2078` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2079` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2080` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2081` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2082` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2083` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2084` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2085` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2086` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2087` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2088` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2089` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2090` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3000` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3001` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3002` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3003` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3004` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3005` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3006` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3007` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3008` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3009` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3010` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3011` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3012` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3013` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3014` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3015` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3016` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3017` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3018` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3019` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3020` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3021` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC3022` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC6000` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC6001` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC6002` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7000` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7001` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7002` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7003` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7004` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7005` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7006` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7007` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7008` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7009` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7010` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7011` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7012` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7013` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7014` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7015` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7016` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7017` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7018` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7019` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7020` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7021` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7022` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7023` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7024` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC7025` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC8000` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8001` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8002` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8003` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8004` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8005` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8006` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8007` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8008` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8009` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8010` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8011` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8012` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8013` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8014` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8015` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8016` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8017` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8018` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8019` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8020` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8021` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8022` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8023` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8024` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8025` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8026` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8027` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8028` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8029` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8030` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8031` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8032` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC8033` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`CFC2091` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2092` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2093` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`CFC2094` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_ATT_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_SUC_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_DRP_BAD_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_V_PRIM_CALL_ERL` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_V_MOU_TMS` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_BTS_UNA_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_SYN_TO_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_NOT_ACQ_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_HCM_TO_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_BAD_FRM_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_MSC_DRP_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_ETC_FAIL_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_MOB_REL_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL, 
`R3_M_MSC_CLR_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL
`R3_M_DRP_ETC_CNT` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`BSM_ID` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
`BSC_SEQ_ID` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=BRIGHTHOUSE;
```

Here is a sample of the output as well:

```
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,1,0,.093888888888888888888888888888888888889,0,19,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,.023055555555555555555555555555555555556,0,1,0,0,0,5,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.38333333333333333333333333333333333333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,1,0,.093888888888888888888888888888888888889,0,19,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,.036111111111111111111111111111111111111,0,5,0,0,0,7,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2.16666666666666666666666666666666666667,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,.04,0,12,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,.036111111111111111111111111111111111111,0,5,0,0,0,7,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2.16666666666666666666666666666666666667,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,.04,0,12,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,7,0,.627777777777777777777777777777777777778,0,18,0,0,0,82,82,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37.6666666666666666666666666666666666667,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,57,0,0,0,53,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,12,0,.247777777777777777777777777777777777778,0,32,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,57,0,0,0,53,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Please post a few lines of the file and exact table definition

Comment: I added the create table statement I used but I don't know how to copy a few lines of the csv file as I can't open it since it is about 4gb in size...

Comment: although when I look at the file preview in import tool in sql server, the date shows as mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mm:ss....dont know if that helps

Comment: It's important to see how values in your file look like. In order to print out first two lines of your big file start a command prompt `cmd.exe` and then use command `more +2 C:/import/IPORT17/IPORT17.csv`

Comment: updated..thanks for the tip peterm!